# Constant speed in curved space

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, velocity

Suppose a spaceship is travelling in the [Schwarzschild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric). An observer at infinity sees the spaceship moving at *constant velocity*. What does this mean?

Does it mean that:

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{g_{ij}\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt}} = {\rm constant?}
\end{align*}

or

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt}} = {\rm constant?}
\end{align*}

or maybe some other quantity?

(What would it mean if the spaceship driver saw himself travelling at constant velocity?)

Comment: Is it constant *speed* or constant *velocity* that is observed?

Comment: Constant velocity... but should it really matter? Velocity is merely speed with a direction, right?

Comment: A circular orbit has constant speed but not constant velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems a bit misleading. If your hypothesis is constant coordinate velocity ( that is $ \dfrac{dx^\nu}{dt}=const $, but often is better to work with proper velocity $ \dfrac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=const $ with $ \tau=proper \; time $) seen by the distant observer, then the second quantity is constant. By the way, the Schwarzschild metric is independent of time, so even the first quantity is conserved.